# Java 10 JavaFX java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, module, java-10

I'm trying to update my JavaFX Gradle project to Java 10. I've changed my build.gradle file like in [this guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle). But when I try to run the project (execute `./gradle run`), I get this error:

```
> Task :run FAILED
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x5ce4f9a4) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x5ce4f9a4
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
        at com.project.example.Main.start(Main.java:16)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application com.project.example.Main

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

So the problem is that the class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils. What causes this problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The log that relates to the actual problem is **`module javafx.graphics` does not *export* `com.sun.javafx.util` to *unnamed module***

Comment: You need to change your build script to include `javafx.fxml` module, or it will be loaded from the classpath and added to the unnamed module (`javafx.graphics` module doesn't/can't export `com.sun.javafx.util` package to the unnamed module): `'--add-modules', 'javafx.fxml, javafx.controls'`

Comment: the snippet that @nullpointer highlighted contains the solution (if the modules are already added correctly) - whenever you see such a line, you need to the add the appropriate --add-xx param to the runtime context by mapping that line into _--add-<missing-operation> <module>/<missing-package>=<target-module>_ in your case:  _--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED_ (don't know how/where to do that in gradle, though)

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to add the `javafx.fxml` module into your VM Arguments. To do so, follow these steps:

> Run >> Run Configurations

Add this line to VM Arguments:

`--module-path "C:\your\path\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Make sure the class you want to run is selected on the right-side of the window.

For more information, please access the **Getting Started** from the JavaFX Documentation on this link: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx